# Why is there set data structure implemented in C++ when the same thing can be done using map?

Tags: c++11, set, binary-tree

Why is there an implementation of set data structure in C++ when the same thing can be done using map, although map will take 2*n space rather than n but it should not affect anything. I have read about set and map and only significant difference is key and value, which is not convincing.

Comment: Using half as much space sounds pretty convincing on its own.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just answered your own question. I believe that one of the reasons is that it takes twice as much space to store if you use a map instead of set. Another reason I think is for the old and gold clean code.